# Question: Howto change a funtion to a class in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I want to create a class with methods, so that I do not have to create multiple functions.
Below is my code, I want to get a class with two methods. Method 1: SQL Query, method 2: sql insert.

Any tipp is greatly appreciated.

Stefan

```
def dbconnect():
    dbconn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.1.2', port=3307,  user='username', passwd='password', db='dbname')
    try:
        cur = dbconn.cursor()
        sqlQuery = "select * from data"
        sqlQuerygetlast = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
        sqlQuerygetlast10 = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"
        cur.execute(sqlQuerygetlast10)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))
    finally:
        #dbconn.commit()
        dbconn.close()
```

My objective is to call the methods from my code, i.e. query a select statement.

Thanks a lot
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean that you don't want to create multiple connections?

Then you should implement it as a [Context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html):

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbconn = None

    def get_last(self, n)
        try:
            cur = self.dbconn.cursor()
            sqlQuerygetlast = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {}".format(n)
            cur.execute(sqlQuerygetlast)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print(row)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))
        finally:
            # self.dbconn.commit()

    def some_other_method(self):
        self.dbconn.do_something()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.dbconn = pymysql.connect(
            host='192.168.1.2', 
            port=3307,  
            user='username', 
            passwd='password', 
            db='dbname'
        )
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        dbconn.close()
        return True
```

and use it as follows:

```
with DB() as db:
    db.get_last(1)
    db.get_last(10)
    db.some_other_method()
```

This will create only one instance of a database connection and close after it is finished.

Comment: Hello Yevhen,
thank you very much, your solution hits the objective excatly! Rwegards, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Writing a class in Python is fairly simple.

Here's an example of how to write the classic Person class and how to use properties and methods.

Specifically, the **presentation** method is also making use of the **name** property.

From this example you can move on and build your Database class implementation quite easily:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def presentation(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.presentation()
```

Remember that in all the methods of a class you will have to specify the reserved keyword self as parameter (plus, clearly, any other parameter you might need).

Comment: Hi Pitto,
thanky to you to, your answer is valueable, too.

Comment: It is my pleasure, @Stefan.
I didn't want to write down a complete solution you but to give suggestions and tips to proceed in your quest.
If you liked my answer please remember to upvote it when you'll have sufficent reputation.
Happy hacking :)